# How do you load paginated data that updates constantly?

Tags: algorithm

I am building a typical images collage page where you scroll down to lazy load similar to Google Images search. This page also has ability to sort the displayed images. If the underlying data is constantly being added / removed, how does one deal with not showing duplicates with sorting turned on? Is there a well known algorithm for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understood corretly your issue is that you have the position of a last displayed record and when you fecth the next those might be the one you already had because because some records have been inserted on top of it.

if that is the case, try to do not use the position of the record but the actuall value you are using for sorting.

let's say is value and your last element is A.
you want: next N record where value>A.value sorted by value.

you will not replicate but you will "miss" those with value less than A.value, unless you reload also when "going back".

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about this but didn't quite like the missing data greater than A. I guess there's not much you can do in this case.